# Static files not served by js-test-driver

Tags: static, assets, js-test-driver

I'm using js-test-driver to run some tests and would like to test some code against an html document.  I was hoping to load this into the current document in an iframe and test my code against it but I'm having trouble even getting the file.

My directory structure is:

- simpleJsTestDriver

  - aFile.html
  - aTest.js
  - jsTestDriver.conf
  - jsTestDriver.jar
  - someCode.js

**afile.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    hello
  </body>
</html>
```

**jsTestDriver.conf**

```
server: http://localhost:9876

load:
  - "someCode.js"

test:
  - "aTest.js"

serve:
  - "aFile.html"
```

Running `java -jar JsTestDriver.jar --port 9876 --runnerMode=DEBUG`  and navigating to `http://localhost:9876/aFile.html` gives:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /aFile.html. Reason:

    Not found.
Powered by Jetty://
```

I'm using the latest version of js-test-driver (1.3.4.b) as 1.3.4.a appeared to have this [problem of not serving](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/issues/detail?id=376) static files.  I know that the server finds the file okay as changing the name in the conf file to `aFi.html` throws the error:

```
Configuration Error: 
Cannot read [
/Users/james/Documents/simpleJSTestDriver/./aFi.html
] derived from aFi.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally just solved it.  You need to navigate to `http://localhost:9876/`**test**`/aFile.html`.  Obviously!

Comment: So the instructions here really aren't that helpful right or is it obvious to everyone else?  http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/ConfigurationFile#serve: